# How can I check available space of an index's pages in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, vacuum

For tables, I can simply use pg_freespace to check available spaces like below:

```
postgres=> SELECT count(*),avg(1000*avail/8192)/10 FROM pg_freespace('tablename');
  count  |        ?column?        
---------+------------------------
 1978140 | 1.00397105361602313000
```

But for indexes, it does not work.

```
postgres=> SELECT count(*),avg(1000*avail/8192)/10 FROM pg_freespace('tablename_pkey');
  count  |          ?column?          
---------+----------------------------
 1224867 | 0.000000000000000000000000
```

Additionally, this is the result of same queries after VACUUM FULL:

```
postgres=> SELECT count(*),avg(1000*avail/8192)/10 FROM pg_freespace('tablename');
  count  |          ?column?          
---------+----------------------------
 1833413 | 0.000000000000000000000000
postgres=> SELECT count(*),avg(1000*avail/8192)/10 FROM pg_freespace('tablename_pkey');
 count  |          ?column?          
--------+----------------------------
 836994 | 0.000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Albeit not very prominently, the [documentation of `pg_freespacemap`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgfreespacemap.html) mentions the following:

> For indexes, what is tracked is entirely-unused pages, rather than free space within pages. Therefore, the values are not meaningful, just whether a page is full or empty.

Your query results simply mean that you don't have a single fully free index page.

Comment: Thanks,but is there any extension for indexes available space check?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any.  Why do you need it?  There might be something else that fits your use case.